# Problem with ping (open socket: Operation not permitted)

Tags: debian, ping

I have such trouble when using `ping 127.0.0.1` under root:

```
ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted
```

What does it mean? When I try `ls -l /bin/ping` it says:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 30788 Jul 27  2010 /bin/ping
```

I'm using Debian GNU/Linux 5.0

Answer (score 16):

After few search I found `setcap` and :

```
setcap cap_net_raw=ep $(which ping)
```

Comment: I had that problem with the default installation of SparkyLinux (facepalm). Zulu's solution fixed it.

Comment: I had this with a Debian chroot inside an Ubuntu 14.04, and executing this to the debian executable while not chroot'ed fixed it.

Comment: This fixed the problem on Raspbian 8.

Comment: -bash: setcap: command not found

Answer (score 1):

You might have an `iptables` rule preventing pings from getting to localhost (this is entirely possible with iptables).

The following will clear all `iptables` rules.  Do this cautiously because `iptables` is used to implement firewalling on Linux, so you are effectively disabling your firewall.

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F
iptables -X
```

This could happen if your route table is messed up, I believe, as well.  Give us the output of `route` if the above leads nowhere.

The only other thing I can think of is that you have `lo`, the localhost "virtual network adapter", involved in some weird bridging configuration with another adapter.  But this is highly unlikely (but you can use `brctl` to check).

Comment: I have real IP that's why I don't want to open totally computer to world in case of clearing iptables. ifconfig says besides lo: `lo:4 Link encap:Local Loopback inet addr:92.xxx.xxx.xxx Mask:255.255.255.255 UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1`. `brctl` not found.

Comment: # iptables --list
`FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.34-vs2.3.0.36.30.4.pre8/modules.dep: No such file or directory
iptables v1.4.2: can't initialize iptables table filter': Permission denied (you must be root)`

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ping_group_range="0 1000"
```

Comment: To make this change permanent, create a file such as `/etc/sysctl.d/ping.conf` (the name can be anything as long as it ends with `.conf`) containing line `net.ipv4.ping_group_range = 0 2147483647` and [reload sysctl](https://superuser.com/q/625840/162491).