# How do I reload sysctl from sysctl.d directory?

Tags: ubuntu

I am making changes to a file in the `/etc/sysctl.d` directory (Ubuntu 12.04).

I know that `sysctl -p` reloads from `/etc/sysctl.conf` but it doesn't seem to work for anything under the `/etc/sysctl.d/` directory. A reboot works, but I'd like to do it without a reboot.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 77):

As [documented](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man8/sysctl.8.html), for recent *util-linux* versions:

```
# Load settings from all system configuration files
sysctl --system
```

For older versions (that is, if `--system` does not work):

```
# Load settings from /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p
```

```
# Load settings from the specified file
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/<whatever>.conf
```

Answer (score 11):

The README file in `/etc/sysctl.d/` on an Ubuntu 12.04 system with procps 1:3.2.8-11ubuntu6.3 says to run:

```
service procps start
```

Which ends up running (via `/etc/init/procps.conf`) this:

```
cat /etc/sysctl.d/*.conf /etc/sysctl.conf | sysctl -e -p -
```

Answer (score 0):

On newer systemd-based systems, the preferred procedure is to either run `systemd-sysctl` manually:

```sh
systemd-sysctl
```

or restart the corresponding service:

```sh
systemctl restart systemd-sysctl
```

Source: systemd-sysctl [manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-sysctl.service.html)