# How to change the "default" value of sysctl?

Tags: linux

In Linux, it seems when you change/set values in sysctl, sysctl will apply these settings every boot on-the-fly, but the settings will remain default until sysctl starts and apply the user set values.

How to change the default value so they will constantly be the user-set ones, thus eliminate the time-window of them being default?

Or am I wrong in the first place (sysctl actually change the value permanently)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Updated Answer

The "default" value of many `sysctl` kernel parameters is compiled into the kernel itself.

*Example:* `kernel.numa_balancing_scan_delay_ms` is set to `1000` by default in [`./kernel/sched/fair.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/89c9fea3c8034cdb2fd745f551cde0b507fd6893/kernel/sched/fair.c), which is loaded in [`./kernel/sysctl.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/bf5f89463f5b3109a72ed13ca62b57e90213387d/kernel/sysctl.c#L366).

You can change these at **runtime with `sysctl`**<sup>3</sup>.  systemd does this at boot with [`systemd-sysctl.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-sysctl.service.html) early in the boot process.

For some reason, it sounds like you are initializing something very early that a kernel parameter can't be set later and must be set on boot.  If early boot service is still too late and you can't tolerate `sysctl` setting parameters that late, perhaps you can **[set the parameters at boot](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bootparam.7.html)**<sup>2</sup> in your bootloader's kernel line.

If you can't do that, you may need to **compile a custom kernel**<sup>1</sup> with the default values you want.

[From the Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_parameters):

> There are three ways to pass options to the kernel and thus control
>   its behaviour:
>
> 1. When building the kernel. See [Kernel Compilation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_Compilation) for details.
> 2. When starting the kernel (usually, when invoked from a boot loader).
> 3. At runtime (through the files in `/proc` and `/sys`). See [sysctl](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sysctl) for details.

---

## Original Answer

Set the values in `/etc/sysctl.conf` or in a `*.conf` file in `/etc/sysctl.d/`.

Once they're set, you can reload the configuration by running `sudo sysctl --system`.

---

### Additional Resources

- [How to reload sysctl.conf variables on Linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/reload-sysctl-conf-on-linux-using-sysctl/) on nixCraft
- [How do I reload sysctl from sysctl.d directory?](https://superuser.com/q/625840/83694) on Super User
- `man 8 sysctl`

Comment: Sorry but you may not understand my question. I should've ask another question before this. Let's say value A's default is 0, now I set it to 1 via sysctl, I reboot the system and read A is 1 as expected. Then I disable sysctl from auto-start on boot, and reboot the computer, what is A this time?

Comment: @Sam: A is 0. Defaults are often built into the kernel. Example: `kernel.numa_balancing_scan_delay_ms` is set to `1000` by default in [`./kernel/sched/fair.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/89c9fea3c8034cdb2fd745f551cde0b507fd6893/kernel/sched/fair.c), which is loaded in [`./kernel/sysctl.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/bf5f89463f5b3109a72ed13ca62b57e90213387d/kernel/sysctl.c#L366). If you can't tolerate `sysctl` setting a parameter later in boot, perhaps you can set the parameter at boot in your bootloader's kernel line.  If you can't do that, you may need a custom kernel.